# Always failed when POST data with json (body: raw)

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I'm have trouble when send data to my server. I'm working with react native & axios ver ^0.16.2

```
let input = {
  'longitude': -6.3922782,
  'latitude': 106.8268856,
  'content': 'uget - uget sampai kaki lemes',
  'pictures': []
}

  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.state.headers.authorization
    },
    data: input
  })                                                                     
  .then((resultAxios) => {
    console.log('hasil axios', resultAxios)
  })
```

and the status result always error 500.

If I try send data with postman, everything is fine. In postman, I set

```
headers: {
  Authorization: ''',
  Content-Type: application/json
}

body = raw, JSON
```

[image: postman setting]

How can solve this problem? Thanks :)

Comment: Any server logs?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify(input)`?

Comment: Pretty sure the comment above is the solution. If you run Telerik Fiddler you can see the actual requests which might help you debug when it's not what you expect, and allow you to quickly see the difference between the postman request and your own.

Comment: Looks like there's a typo with `url`.

Comment: im already JSON.stringify(input) , but the result is still same.. i think there is someting configuration for headers..

Answer (score 1):

I've found that axios have some problem in the processing of json for body
try this:

```
let input = 'longitude=-6.3922782&latitude=106.8268856&content="uget - uget sampai kaki lemes"&pictures=[]';

  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.state.headers.authorization
    },
    data: input
  })                                                                     
  .then((resultAxios) => {
    console.log('hasil axios', resultAxios)
  })
```

and the status result always error 500.

If I try send data with postman, everything is fine. In postman, I set

```
headers: {
  Authorization: ''',
  Content-Type: application/json
}

body = raw, JSON
```

Answer (score 1):

@Davide

That is correct, its an Axios bug I found as well..

AND the errors I found were CORS preflight errors, which had NOTHING to do with the actual problem

** FAIL **

```
Axios({
method: "post",
url: "https://localhost:44394/EXAMPLE/",
data: jsonPayload,
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
})
```

** SUCCESS **

```
Axios({
method: "post",
url: "https://localhost:44394/EXAMPLE/",
data: JSON.Stringify(jsonPayload),
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
})
```